# WebSocket handshake error net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to connect Paho JS lib to Snap! to allow communication with server through MQTT protocol, but somehow WebSockets keep crashing on me.

Here's the code i use:

```
var wsbroker = "127.0.0.1";
var wsport = 9001;

console.log("Connecting to: ", wsbroker);
console.log("Connecting to port: ", Number(wsport));

client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, Number(wsport),"Snap");

// set callback handlers
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
var client_options = {
    onSuccess:onConnect,
    onFailure:doFail
}

client.connect(client_options);

// called when the client connects
function onConnect() {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log("Client connected...");
    client.subscribe("/Navicula/test");
    message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("CONNECTED");
    message.destinationName = "/Navicula/test";
    client.send(message);
}

function doFail(e){
    console.log("I haz failed");
    console.log(e);
}

// called when the client loses its connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
        console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
}

// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
```

mqttws31.min.js is implemented before (used mqttws31.js but the same results).

I have mosquitto 1.4.8 installed with following config:

```
    # Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
    #
    # A full description of the configuration file is at
    # /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

    pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

    listener 1883 127.0.0.1 protocol mqtt 
    listener 9001 127.0.0.1 protocol websockets

    persistence true
    persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

    log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

    include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

The JS code runs from html file on pythons SimpleHTTPServer and after running always prints this in console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

with this as error code on onFail function:

```
Object {invocationContext: undefined, errorCode: 7, errorMessage: "AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined."}
```

On the server side (mosquitto) i get following log:

```
1496269205: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:03:16 +0100) starting
1496269205: Config loaded from myconf.conf.
1496269205: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1496269205: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 9001.
1496269215: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 9001.
1496269215: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1496269215: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 9001.
1496269215: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1496269224: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 9001.
1496269224: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1496269224: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 9001.
1496269224: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

So i guess it must be fault somewhere in the code part, but i'm totally lost here.

Answer (score 0):

The `protocol` definition should be on a separate line to the `listener` in the configuration file. At the moment they are being ignored so both listeners are being interpreted as native MQTT.

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

listener 1883 127.0.0.1 
protocol mqtt 

listener 9001 127.0.0.1 
protocol websockets

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

Comment: I have the same error, my config listener and protocols are same as you described (without the 127.0.0.1). what else could have gone wrong? I'm able to publish and subscribe to messages only when using another mosquitto instance

Comment: @TheUnreal all a new question (reference this one of needed) and include your own logs and config file so we can set of it is exactly the same problem